# Formatting text boxes for postal codes & zip codes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a text box where the user gets to enter a zip code or a postal code; though as we know, each are different from each other
(A postal code can be A1B2C3 while a zip code can be 12345)

How would I make it so if makes them put the codes in the text box where it auto capitalizes the input if it's text, and doesn't let them put spaces?

I've tried using a mask, but it makes me limit the amount of characters they can enter and each has a different amount so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this purely at the UI level by handling the text box's KeyDown and KeyPress events:

```
Private Sub txtPostCode_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = vbKeySpace Then KeyCode = 0
End Sub

Private Sub txtPostCode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc("a") To Asc("z")
      KeyAscii = KeyAscii + Asc("A") - Asc("a")
  End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried using a mask, but it makes me limit the amount of characters they can enter and each has a different amount so it doesn't work.

You don't necessarily have to settle for just one Input Mask. You can arrange your form so that the Country gets entered before the Postal Code, and then adjust the Input Mask accordingly. For example, if you use a Combo Box for the Country, then it could have an After Update event handler like

```vbs
Private Sub cbxCountry_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strMask As String
    strMask = ""
    If Not IsNull(Me.cbxCountry.Value) Then
        Select Case Me.cbxCountry.Value
            Case "Canada"
                strMask = ">L0L 0L0"
            Case "U.S.A."
                strMask = "00000-9999"
        End Select
    End If
    Me.txtPostalCode.InputMask = strMask
End Sub
```

These things *can* be a bit fussy, but it might ultimately give you better results than a "one size fits all" approach would.

..and Canadian postal codes **do** have a space in them, but looking at your profile I'm pretty sure you know that.... ;)